# view or open a Spyder variable without double clicking on it

Tags: python, spyder

Is there any way to automatically open a created variable in the Spyder without double clicking on it in the variable explorer, each time I update my code?

Comment: What does "open a variable" mean?

Comment: I suggest you read spider docs for this: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/

Comment: @deceze Let's say your code generates a dataframe and it can be opened by double clicking on it in the variable explorer section of the Spyder. I wanted to see if there is any automatic way of doing this without manually double clicking on it to open

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, that's not possible at the moment, sorry.